# Ajax returning an undefine value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I have a search function that is suppose to search a name from the database, and then when the user clicks add, the item choosen has to appear below the search field, in short it has to be posted back so that the user can re-select his/her second option from the search element so that all the selected options can be saved in the database. The problem im facing is that after I click add im getting undefined value back instead of the one I choose and my response is a name instead of an Id number, here is my code and a picture below.

MODEL

```
public function getName($id)
    {
        $select = $this->select()
                         ->where('service_provider_id  LIKE "' . $id . '%"')
                         ->order('service_provider_name');
        return $this->fetchAll($select);
    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
  {
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    $mdlserviceprovider = new Model_ServiceProviders();
    $serviceprovider  = $mdlserviceprovider ->getName($id);
    $arr_rtn = array();
    if (count($results) > 0){
        foreach($results as $result)
        {
            $myarr = array( 'label' => $result->service_provider_name,
                            'value'    => $result->service_provider_name,
                            'id' => $result->service_provider_id
                            );
            array_push($arr_rtn, $myarr);
        }
    }
    echo Zend_Json::encode($arr_rtn);
}
```

PHTML/AJAX

```
$('#add1').click(function(){


                  var data = {};
                  data['sp'] = $("#search").val();          

                  $.ajax({
                       url:'<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/ajax/postserviceprovider/id',
                       type:'post',
                       dataType: "json",
                       data: data,        
                       success:function(data){
                         var row = '<tr><td>' + data["serviceprovider"] + '</td></tr>';
                         $('#t1').append(row);
                        //alert();  
                      }               
                  });
                });
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a key that doesn't exist in the array you are returning try this

```
var row = '<tr><td>' + data['label'] + '</td></tr>';
```

Or this

```
var row = '<tr><td>' + data['value'] + '</td></tr>';
```

As those are the two keys you defined in your PHP page

Comment: Still getting undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data["value"]` instead of `data["serviceprovider"]`:

```
var row = '<tr><td>' + data["value"] + '</td></tr>';
```

Since you've encoded the array which contains three keys: `label`, `value` and `id`. So there's no `serviceprovider` key at this moment for Zend to encode.

Comment: Still getting undefined

Comment: Try to use `data[0].value`. Also make sure that your `$results` contain value. Try to use `var_dump($results)` or `print_r($results)` to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var row = '<tr><td>' + data[0].value + '</td></tr>';
```

Also try to put an `alert()` in the success function like,

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

and see what is included in it..

Comment: Nothing posts back this time

Answer (score 0):

From what I see I think you are ruturning a multidimensional array from php so I would try something like this in javascript:

```
$('#add1').click(function(){


                  var data = {};
                  data['sp'] = $("#search").val();          

                  $.ajax({
                       url:'<?php echo $this->baseUrl()?>/ajax/postserviceprovider/id',
                       type:'post',
                       dataType: "json",
                       data: data,        
                       success:function(data){
                         data.each(function(index, el){
                             var row = '<tr><td>' + el.label + '</td></tr>';
                             $('#t1').append(row);
                             //alert();  
                        }
                      }               
                  });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try:

```
$this->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
return $this->_helper->json(array('key1' => $val1, 'key2' => $val2, ...));
```

Comment: Im geting null values returned

Comment: your $arr_rtn is null?

Comment: Nah the values that are posted back after clicking add are null

Comment: What is your $id value in your controller? You can use a log to see that.

Comment: its suppose to get the value selected from the search element

Comment: Try for testing javascript side: return $this->_helper->json(array( 'label' => 'NameTest', 'value' => 'ValueTest', 'id' => 'IdTest')); and see the value in ajax succes ou ajax error. If you not receive this value => is the problem before sending

Comment: im getting null and undefined

Comment: with an hard array, you get null and undefined, right? if yes, have you a plugin with a post with postDispatch() or dispatchLoopShutdown()?

Comment: put a log message like $log->info("foo"); just before return in your action to see if you reach the end

Comment: Got it working hadf to fix my db queriries ->where('service_provider_id  = ?', $id); and how I was calling them back

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. getName($id) is good? (return somthing?) or not?